# EF hard coded value in WHERE clause is fast, string parameter is slow

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am experiencing a very slow performance when I set a string variable in my EF Where clause and very fast performance when I hard code the string value in the where clause.

C#, .Net Framework 4.7.1, EF 6.2

**50ms**

```
db.Dealers.Where(x => x.SourceDealerId == "000111222fff333q");
```

**1.5seconds**

```
var parameter = "000111222fff333q";
db.Dealers.Where(x => x.SourceDealerId== parameter );
```

The dealerId is of type Char(18) in the Database and it is nullable.
The approach is Database first.
Here are the properties of the dealer column:
[image]

There is difference in the SQL that is generated in both cases.
For the fast case:
...`WHERE dealerId = '000111222fff333q'`

For the slow case:

[image]

Comment: Your code looks odd. Shouldn't it be `.Where(x => x.SourceDealerID == parameter)` (or `... == "000111222fff333q")`?

Comment: it is like this, I didn't copy paste the exact code. Please ignore that, I need to see why the performance is bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be related to  NULL comparison setting in Entity Framework

add the following code before your query to see if it helps your query performance:

```
context.ContextOptions.UseCSharpNullComparisonBehavior = false;
```

Comment: Please edit your answer so I can mark it. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

As you can see, when you use a parameter, EF adds a null comparison check, to mimic the behavior of null comparison in C#. While in C#, `null == null` is True, in SQL, `NULL = NULL` is False. Depending on the size of your table, this could affect your performance.

You have two options here:

1. The preferred one in my opinion is to add an index to the table on the `SourceDealerID` column. Note that an index has a performance impact on updates and inserts, so you should test that.
2. Disable the null check, and remember that your LINQ query behaves like SQL and not like C#. This can be done by setting [`UseDatabaseNullSemantics` to `true`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbcontextconfiguration.usedatabasenullsemantics?view=entity-framework-6.2.0).

Comment: Thanks, for the moment I don't have permissions to add index and there are 10 more filters which are in the WHERE clause, so that would be 10 indexes which we don't want. How do I apply 2) in my code?

Comment: @st_stefanov In the constructor of the class that inherits `DbContext`, access the `Configurtion` property and set the `UseDatabaseNullSemantics` of the object it returns.